# JQuery Slider With Multiple Animations/Effects

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, uislider

I'm looking to create a slider where one image fades in, then another fades in next to it, then the slide changes. Thus far I've tried using "wowslider" and "rhinoslider" and googled it extensively... however I cannot seem to find a slider tool where this can be accomplished. Every tool I've tried and read about allows for a fade in effect - but only for one image per slide - I need to fade in two images [one, then the other] then change slides.

How might this be accomplished? (either with an existing tool such as wowslider - or perhaps using pure code)

Any suggestions are GREATLY appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

you could use http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel Bootstrap Carousel Plugin.

it has an event handler for between slide times:

```
$('#myCarousel').on('slide.bs.carousel', function () {
  // do something…
  // This event fires immediately when the slide instance method is invoked.
})
```

or

```
$('#myCarousel').on('slid.bs.carousel', function () {
 // do something…
 // This event is fired when the carousel has completed its slide transition.
})
```

you can use the second one and instead of `//do something` you can write your fade function. I mean by this: you put two images under each slide. after slide is complete, faceOut the first shown image and fadeIn the second hidden image.